# Docker push image to Nexus gives invalid checksum digest format error

Tags: docker, sonatype, nexus3

I'm trying to push images from Docker Desktop from Windows machine as Linux containers to Nexus system in Linux system. When I tried to push Docker images gives error as:

```
invalid checksum digest format
```

It's my first time using Nexus repository for Docker.

I am using Nexus Sonatype Repository Manager version 3.20.1-01 and Docker desktop version 2.1.0.5.

Comment: Which version of docker are you using ?

Comment: Docker desktop version 2.1.0.5